# python xarray - update subset of values

Tags: python, python-xarray

I need to update values in a Xarray DataArray. There are only certain values I want to update, which are stored in a dataframe together with their coordinates.

One can also reformulate the problem as both (i) update a non-continuous (non-rectangular) area of values in a DataArray and (ii) left-join dataset with new values on matching coords and rewrite old values.

Intial DataArray (Dataset):

```
import xarray as xr
import pandas as pd

ds = xr.Dataset(
    data_vars = {"x": (("a", "b"), np.zeros((3, 4)))},
    coords = {"a": np.arange(3), "b": np.arange(4)})
ds.x.values    

array([[0., 0., 0., 0.],
      [0., 0., 0., 0.],
      [0., 0., 0., 0.]])
```

New values to assign with their coordinates:

```
new_val = pd.DataFrame([
    (0, 1, 10),
    (1, 0, 11),
    (2, 2, 12)],
    columns=['a', 'b', 'x'])
```

Result I want to get:

```
array([[0., 10., 0., 0.],
      [11., 0., 0., 0.],
      [0., 0., 12., 0.]])
```

I was trying to use methods both in [Combining data](https://xarray.pydata.org/en/v2022.06.0/user-guide/combining.html) and in [Assigning values with indexing](https://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/user-guide/indexing.html#assigning-values-with-indexing) turials, but no luck so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Result can be achieved using `combine_first`.

```
# set index and convert to xr Dataset
new_val_idx = new_val.set_index(['a', 'b'])
new_val_ds = xr.Dataset.from_dataframe(new_val_idx)

combined = new_val_ds.combine_first(ds)
combined.x.values

array([[ 0., 10.,  0.,  0.],
       [11.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0., 12.,  0.]])
```